# Losing Records while uploading file to GCS bucket using cloud storage Python client library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

For context, I'm running a Vertex AI pipeline. In one of my pipeline components, I am running the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

file_1_name = '<insert csv file 1 name>'
file_2_name = '<insert csv file 2 name>'

archive_bucket = storage_client.bucket(archive_bucket_name)
upload_bucket = storage_client.bucket(target_bucket_name)

# generate list of blobs in the prediction bucket
target_bucket_blobs = list(upload_bucket.list_blobs())

# if no blobs exist, this means that we can write to the bucket
# create a blob name for files to be uploaded as
if not target_bucket_blobs:
    pass
# if blobs do exist, this means that we should delete the existing blobs in bucket
else:
    # DELETE BLOBS FIRST
    for blob in target_bucket_blobs:
        upload_bucket.copy_blob(blob, archive_bucket, blob.name)
        blob.delete()

# make script sleep for 5 minutes until the files have been deleted and copied to new bucket
time.sleep(300)

# NOW WRITE PREDICTIONS
# Tag all predictions with the timestamp
current_time = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d - %Hh-%Mm-%Ss")
# upload file as blob name in specified bucket
print(f'Uploading predictions to {target_bucket_name}.')

file_1_blob = upload_bucket.blob(file_1_name + '_' + current_time)
file_2_blob = upload_bucket.blob(file_2_name + '_' + current_time)

file_1_blob.upload_from_filename(file_1_path, content_type='text/csv')
file_2_blob.upload_from_filename(file_2_path, content_type='text/csv')
```

For those that use the google-cloud-storage python library, this should be somewhat familiar, but if not, follow the comments in the code.

At a high level, this is what is happening, I have 2 buckets, an archive bucket and an upload bucket. I have a machine learning pipeline (Vertex AI pipeline) where, in the last pipeline component, I am running the above code. The ML pipeline generates 2 files (predictions), file_1 and file_2. The upload bucket houses these predictions, to be read by another service.

What I am trying to accomplish with my code is the following:

- check the upload bucket to see if it is populated with any objects, if so, archive these objects in the bucket (by copying them to my archive bucket), then delete these objects in the upload bucket
- then upload file_1 and file_2, generated by the run of the ML pipeline, to the upload bucket

**My issue:**

The former step works perfectly fine, the GCS objects (i.e. existing files in the upload bucket get copied successfully to the archive bucket and get deleted successfully). The latter is where I'm having issues.

When I upload file_1 and file_2 to the upload bucket via the snippet of code:

```
...
file_1_blob = upload_bucket.blob(file_1_name + '_' + current_time)
file_2_blob = upload_bucket.blob(file_2_name + '_' + current_time)

file_1_blob.upload_from_filename(file_1_path, content_type='text/csv')
file_2_blob.upload_from_filename(file_2_path, content_type='text/csv')
```

the uploaded csv files are missing records.

I know this because I outputted the files: file_1, file_2 as artifacts associated to the Vertex AI pipeline component, and they returned the expected number of records, but the remote upload I do via `upload_from_filename()` loses records, seemingly randomly.

Has anyone ever encountered this type of issue before? With the upload to bucket losing records? I'm not entirely sure of the root cause here, if this is an issue with the google cloud storage python library, or if it's something of my doing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the error logs with us so we can help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Are you saying that exact CSV rows are missing and not random data sections?